# Convert Hadoop spark Scala function to Java

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, hadoop, hdfs

Attempting to convert this function from Scala to Java:

```scala
def ib_solr_doc_join_doc_prepare(name: String): RDD[SFCAdTargetingDoc] = {
  val inputPath = INPUT + name

  val data = sc.sequenceFile(inputPath, classOf[Text], classOf[Text]).map(x => x._2.toString)
  data mapPartitions { p =>
    val gson = new Gson
    p map { row =>
      gson.fromJson(row, classOf[SFCAdTargetingDoc])
    }
  }
}
```

As far as I can tell this sc is the spark context object so i used JavaSparkContext like this

```java
JavaRDD<String> j = sc.sequenceFile(args[0], Text.class, Text.class).map(t -> new String(t._2().getBytes()));
```

using gson like this:

```java
GsonBuilder builder = new GsonBuilder();
builder.setPrettyPrinting();

Gson gson = builder.create();
```

The main trouble location is

```scala
data mapPartitions { p =>
  val gson = new Gson
  p map { row =>
    gson.fromJson(row, classOf[SFCAdTargetingDoc])
  }
}
```

data in the is context is a JavaRDD but mapPartitions behaves completely differently in Java than it does in scala.

Comment: What is the difference in behavior exactly? The only reason to blame I can see is new string  creation:
 new String(t._2().getBytes() vs x._2.toString - I think this parts can produce different results

Comment: j.mapPartitions { p->
   
}
p is an iterator that does not have a map function

I have to use forEachRemaining instead. 

also this pops up:
The method mapPartitions(FlatMapFunction<Iterator<String>,U>) in the type AbstractJavaRDDLike<String,JavaRDD<String>> is not applicable for the arguments ((<no type> p) -> {})

Answer (score 0):

I'll try to suggest the solution based on your answer

Yes, java is less convenient for such operations and provides less useful built-in abilities, so you should do it all manually.

The reason why  (p -> {}) is not applicable is that lambda should return *Iterable* to be considered a *FlatMapFunction<.., U>*. And in java, every operator is not an expression, like in scala, and you should specify the value of your function manually.

Moreover, since Iterator doesn't have a map function we are forced to walk through it by ourselves and do the mapping. All of the above leads us to the next solution

```
data.mapPartitions(p -> {
    Gson gson = new Gson()
    List<SCFAdTargetingDoc> result = ArrayList<>();
    while (t.hasNext()) {
      result.add(gson.fromJson(t.next(), SCFAdTargetingDoc.class))
    }

    return result;
})
```

That looks ugly but should work. Also, if you'd like to use scala-like operations, like map, you can consider using Java Streams, which have these functions. But the convertation of an iterator to a stream is not very simple as well. There are various options for how you can do it, I found this one useful:

```
Iterable<String> iterable = () -> i;
Stream<String> sttream = StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false);
```

That transforms our example to this:

```
data.mapPartitions(p -> {
  Iterable<String> iterable = () -> p;
  Stream<String> stream = StreamSupport.stream(iterable.spliterator(), false);

  return stream.map(s -> gson.fromJson(s, 
    SCFAdTargetingDoc.class)).collect(Collectors.toList());
})
```

It's still not as concise as scala code, but its java anyway. If there are many calls like this in your code, you can create separate functions for repeatable operations, such as stream creation and converting to a list, and your code will look like this

```
data.mapPartitions(p -> toList(streamify(p).map(s -> gson.fromJson(s, 
    SCFAdTargetingDoc.class)))
```

This is probably the best you can achieve with java without too much effort.